# How to check if array is of type number and allow + operator

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In the code below I'm getting the following error on `previous + current`:

> Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'T'.

How can I properly check that `T` is `number` in a way that I can both:

- Do `prev + curr`, without getting *Operator '+' cannot be applied*?
- Return the resulting `number`, without getting *Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T'*?

```
function sum<T>(values: T[]): T {
  switch (typeof values[0]) {
    case 'number':
      return values.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0);
    default:
      return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Estradiaz I'm aware of custom type guards, but no idea how to use one in this case.

Comment: What's the use case? Most types don't have a meaningful implementation of `+`. Can you not constrain it?

Comment: Use-case is a table component which you pass an array of data objects, and an array of columns to displayed (`header`, `field`, and optionally a `format` function). Additionally the data will be grouped by a given selector (e.g. by year) with a "totals row" for  each group. To calculate that row of data, I can pass in a custom `sum` function for the column, _but_ I don't want to have to do that in simple cases, like if the columns are just regular numbers. The code as it is works great, I just don't know how to type it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This wont give you the type errors you mentioned. But we have to use the `unknown` type for this.

```
function sum<T>(values: T[]): T {
  switch (typeof values[0]) {
    case 'number':
      return (values.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + <number><unknown>curr, 0)) as unknown as T;
    default:
      return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: This at least gets the type errors away, but wish there was a better way that expressed what I wanted 

Answer (score 1):

A sum of `T[]` doesn't have to be `T` in the general case, consider, for example:

```
type P = 1|2|3;
let ps: P[] = [1,2,3,1,2,3];
```

Obviously, `sum(ps)` won't be `P` anymore.

I think your example is a use case for overloads rather than generics:

```
function sum(a: number[]): number;
function sum(a: any[]): null;

function sum(values: any[]): any {
    if (typeof values[0] === "number")
        return values.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0);
    else
        return null;
}
```

This compiles without problems.

[Play](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/LAKAZgrgdgxgLgSwPZQAQGcIFsAUBDALlSmwCMBTAJwG0BdASiJKwsoG5RJZEUNt8ieKAE86jYhAA2kjiE7R4yNJlwA3PJIjl0gkWN3DUAb1CozqBGFQ44wgA7kkV9Zu3UADLVQBeX6gBEzKz+9Kbm4ZTkcBCUaC5a6AB0kQAmEDDkODh2kaoANKgwMZT0PgB8qDnkqqgA1IXFBe70suHkkujkYeFmkdGxEtKyAL6goJJRxExkVD58uNQAjHkATHkAzHkALHkArAygMCjoSBOJkkgA5jhQpQD0dxIss4u7YyC2DqgACnOLAD4rf7rWQTOCVHQ-OhzJarDZ5ZZrda0WTjSZYabPShzFTZdChEBHKAnM4Xa5Ye6PIIvFbvMGVHH8agAcjwzIKzNI7NQzJgzIOhOOp3I5yu2Upg0kdMmAEdGbhOZI8AArZkSqiUJCUUBAA)